# Test: string is not string

Tags: python, unit-testing

This test result boggles my mind. What could be the fault of this? It is the exact same word after all.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_make_table_list_supplier_unknown (__main__.ConvertingListToDic)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_scraping.py", line 20, in test_make_table_list_supplier_unknown
    self.assertIs(no_supplier_table[0].get('ingredient list')[0]['ingredient'], 'Crystalline Silica')
AssertionError: 'Crystalline Silica' is not 'Crystalline Silica'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assertIs(a, b)` checks if `a` and `b` are the same object.

You probably want to check for value only, in that case use `assertEqual()`

```
self.assertEqual(no_supplier_table[0].get('ingredient list')[0]['ingredient'], 'Crystalline Silica')
```

Note that there is also an `assertEquals()`, which is deprecated so be sure to use `assertEqual()`

See the python docs for more detailed information.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIs

and

https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual

Comment: Thanks! I was reading the docs, but I should have read it more carefully. Also it's kind of curious that `no_supplier_table[0].get('ingredient list')[0].get('ingredient')` works fine with assertIs.

Answer (score 2):

`is` tests object identity. Distinct objects can be equal; what you want is `assertEqual`.